# up2date login & patch APIs for RHEL7

Tags: linux, redhat, patch-management, rpc, rhel7

I am trying to achieve controlled patching of the RHEL machines in my network, for which I need to get the list of all patches onto a windows machine & distribute the missing ones.

I have already familiazired myself with the login & update RPCs for RHN classic registered machines. I have achieved those using the **'systemid file'** & **'up2date.login xmlrpc'**.

But, **on my RHEL7**, the system registration is forced only through **'subscription_manager register'**. This method **doesn't generate a systemid file**. Rather I encountered discussions that this method makes use of certificates.

Can you please tell me how to make RPCs to RHN (http://xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC), in order to get the details of the subscribed channels & ultimately the patches available in those channels?

Thanks

Comment: That's a whole lot of work, just to avoid installing Satellite.

Comment: Yeah, it is easier. But, installing Satellite, requires additional subscriptional charges. Am looking for alternatives to achieve it.

Comment: A caching proxy server?

Comment: Yeah, we are trying to get something similar. But, for the older versions we are able to download using the XMLRPC API. which can be used for all flavors & versions.
Can you please explain how to download the binaries, the first time?